# TFS 2008 - Require database reviewer on check-in

Tags: tfs

I have a team project that contains *n* number of branches, and each branch contains a Database folder in the root.  The database folder is where developers check in views, stored procedures, etc.  We have had some issues with developers checking in SQL Code that was poorly written, introduced performance bottlenecks, and so on.  The DBA has asked me to prevent developers from checking in changes to the Database folder until he has had a chance to review them.

I know that I can add a 'Database Reviewer' as part of a required check-in note, but I don't need a database review every time a developer checks in; I only need the database review to be required if the changeset contains changes to the Database folder. I haven't been able to come up with anything worthwhile on Google, so I don't think that this is functionality that is built in to TFS. Could someone point in the direction of how to resolve this, or explain how they resolved a similar problem in the past?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clear cut solution for this, but you have a few options.

1. Remove the check-in permissions to the Database folder for normal developers and have them send their changes as a Shelveset to the Database guy.
2. Ask the developers to become more professional and have them walk by the SQL guy to review their code with them, so that they will be more proficient in SQL later (would be my preferred choice is the SQL Guy isn't part of the team)
3. Ask the SQL guy to join the team and have him pair with the developers when writing complex SQL scripts (that's even better).
4. There is no option to make the check-in note optional for specific branches, folders or files right built into the product, but by developing a custom checkin policy you could require data to be entered in the Database Reviewed field. [Combine this with the Custom path policy](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/01/which-check-in-policies-do-you-use-with.html) to limit this check-in policy to specific paths in source control.

That custom policy would look something like this:

```
public override PolicyFailure[] Evaluate()
{
    if (
        PendingCheckin.CheckinNotes.CheckinNotes.Values.Any(
            note => note.Name == "Database Reviewed By" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(note.Value)))
    {
        return new PolicyFailure[]{new PolicyFailure("Database Review Required", this) };
    }
    else
    {
        return new PolicyFailure[0];
    }
}
```

Check out this small sample project to see [how you can create a custom checkin policy](https://github.com/jessehouwing/tfstools/tree/master/JesseHouwing.CheckinPolicies). And the [requirements if your Check-in policy needs to support multiple Visual Studio versions](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/01/creating-custom-check-in-policy-pack.html).

TFS 2012 adds a Code Review feature which can be made required using a [3rd party check-in policy](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/05/code-review-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2012.html) (again, combine with the custom path Policy to make it required only for certain paths). There are a few projects on codeplex that provide similar features for older versions of TFS. These include [Team Review](http://teamreview.codeplex.com/) and [TFS Review Workflow](https://tfscodereviewflow.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  I think I can adapt this to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything built in to handle this.  I think the best way to handle it would be to lock down those folders so developers can't check in there.  Create a branch/folder where you can allow the developers to check in there.  This would give the DBAs the ability to review the changes before they merge/migrate them.

TFS 2012 includes a code review workflow that could also be used if you could upgrade TFS.  There is also a custom add-on called Team Review that works with TFS 2008.  It provides a nice workflow but it would still be voluntary.
https://teamreview.codeplex.com/releases/view/40528

Thanks,
Mike